# Mongoose aggregate match if in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a basic document that I am performing an aggregate on to search for the combination of a first and and last name combined:

My document:

```
{
   _id: dmw9294r94
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Smith",
   friends: [28enw93hr, 29nwgkn38]
}
```

My aggregate pipline:

```
User.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "name" : { $concat : [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] },
            "firstName": "$firstName",
            "lastName": "$lastName",
            "username": "$username",
            "friends": "$friends"}
    },{
        $match: {
            "name": {$regex: new RegExp(req.query.query, "i")
        }
    }}]).exec(function(err, results){
        res.json(results);
    }
);
```

How can I add to this to check if a specific user ID exists within that users `friends` array?

I tried the following, although had no luck:

```
$match: {
    "name": {$regex: new RegExp(req.query.query, "i"),
    "friends" {$eq: myVarHere}
}
```

Comment: change `$eq` to `$in` [more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: Tried `$in` too, and still no luck.

Comment: Seems like `$in` works if checking for in an array. I'm trying the other way around, checking if an array contains a value.

Comment: sorry - just remove $eq like this `{$match:{"countries":"USA"}}`, so in your case: `"friends" : myVarHere`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear can you please clarify what you mean by  *I'm trying the other way around*?

Answer (score 0):

As @profesor79 said, you just have to $match for the userid you are interested in:

{$match: {"friends": "user_id_to_find")}

Unless I don't understand the question, it seems to me that $regex is not needed here.

Comment: `$regex` is used to search for a combination of `firstName` and `lastName`. Not very relevant to the question, just thought I'd include it here.